# what is the attribute namespace in XML tag?

Tags: xml

my svg file content below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="15cm" height="15cm">
</svg>
```

what is the width's namespace? is default namespace or "xlink". If you know the answer, could you give w3school reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` attribute is neither in default namespace nor `xlink` namespace. It is, instead, in empty namespace. Attribute need an explicit namespace prefix to be in a namespace (from [XML namespace spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting), emphesize mine) :

> "**Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names**; the *interpretation* of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear."

See previous discussion on this topic here : [XML Default namespaces for unqualified attribute names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312390/xml-default-namespaces-for-unqualified-attribute-names)

Answer (score 0):

The Namespace of width is the same as the one `<svg />` is in! While Elements inherit their default-Namespaces from the enclosing elements, attributes are retrieving them from the element they belong to.

[w3c Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting)