# XAttribute is not aware of sibling XAttribute which IsNamespaceDeclaration

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute

I have to be able to parse both these xml-s:

```
<!-- Case 1 -->
<root xmlns="http://www.xml.namespace/111111">
    <dataObject id="Id1" name="Name1" xmlns="http://www.xml.namespace/222222" />
</root>

<!-- Case 2 -->
<root xmlns:myNs="http://www.xml.namespace/222222">
    <myNs:dataObject myNs:id="Id1" myNs:name="Name1" />
</root>
```

I have to parse the `<dataObject>` (via `XmlSerializer`) into a C# model class which has this:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id", Namespace="http://www.xml.namespace/222222")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

But it only works for `Case 2`, does not work for `Case 1`. 
So I examined `Case 1` with this code:

```
var xmlString = @"<dataObject id=""Id1"" name=""Name1"" xmlns=""http://www.xml.namespace/222222"" />";
var xElement = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var idAttribute = xElement.FirstAttribute;
Console.WriteLine(idAttribute.Name.Namespace); // ""
Console.WriteLine(xElement.Name.Namespace); // "http://www.xml.namespace/222222"
```

Here the `XElement` thinks it has a namespace, while the `XAttribute`s think they don't have any. 
So the `XAttribute`s are somehow not aware of the sibling `xmlns` xml namespace declaration attribute.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Attributes without an explicit namespace prefix will be in no namespace.  The default namespace has no effect, only on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It turnes out it is not a bug, the described behaviour fits the xml specification.

See: 
[XML Default namespaces for unqualified attribute names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312390/xml-default-namespaces-for-unqualified-attribute-names)
[Applying Namespaces to Elements and Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#Philosophy)