# XML Schema Header & Namespace Config

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Migrating from DTD to XSD and for some reason the transition is a bumpy one. I understand how to define the schema once I'm inside the `<xs:schema>` root tag, but getting past the header & namespace declaration stuff is proving to be especially confusing for me.

I have been trying to follow the well-laid out tutorial on [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) but even that tutorial seems to assume a lot of knowledge up front.

I guess what I'm looking for is a King's English explanation of which attributes do what, where they go, and why:

- xmlns
- xmlns:xs
- xmlns:xsi
- targetNamespace
- xsi:schemaLocation

And in some cases I see *different variations* of these elements/attributes, such as `xsi` which seems to have two different notations like `xsi:schemaLocation="..."` and `xs:import schemaLocation="..."`.

I guess between all these slight variations I can't seem to make heads or tails of what each of these does. Thanks in advance for bringing any clarity to this confusion!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to understand are XML namespaces. If you have some time to waste, you could read [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/). I found this to be one of the clearer specs related to XML. It doesn't matter if you don't understand everything it says, it's a good basis. But here's a quick rundown.

XML elements and attributes have a name. When you see `<test att="hello"/>`, you're looking at an element with name "test", in which we have an attribute with name "att". But this isn't really the entire story...

XML is a syntax that allows you to mix content from different markup languages. For example, when using XSLT to turn an XML document into an XHTML page, you're dealing with at least three markup languages defined in XML: your input document's, XSLT and XHTML. Such mixes would become rather hard if each one reserved its own element/attribute names and no collisions were ever allowed.

Enter XML namespaces. An XML namespace defines a "sphere" within which element and attribute names have actual semantics. The element "template" has a well-defined meaning in the XSLT namespace. The element "complexType" has a well-defined meaning in the XML Schema namespace. If you wish to use either in your own markup language using XML, then that's possible provided you do so in a different namespace.

In order to make sure a namespace is unique, you'll need to provide some unique identifier. The specification settled on the use of URIs, most often in the form of a HTTP URL. The reason for this is simple: such URLs tend to be good unique identifiers. But it's also a very common cause for confusion because people think the URLs really hold meaning or will be accessed over the network during XML processing. **Know very well that this is not the case!** The URL is not required to point to any existing resource. It will not go through any transformation or be resolved to a network address. Even if two URLs would point to the exact same thing, the moment they differ by one character they are considered different namespaces. A namespace identifier is just a string, and a case-sensitive one at that. Nothing more.

With the introduction of namespaces, the name of an XML element or attribute suddenly consists of two parts: a namespace and a local name. That "test" in `<test/>` is only the local name. The so-called "fully-qualified name" consists of a kinda invisible combination of the namespace and the local name. Sometimes the notation `{namespace URI}local-name` is used, but that's nothing more than convention.

So now we need to be able to use namespaces in an XML document. In order to declare a namespace, XML has a hard-coded mechanism. It uses the special string `xmlns` to allow namespace declarations to be made. It can be done in one of two ways: binding the namespace to a prefix, or declaring it as the default namespace.

When binding to a prefix, the form is something like this: `xmlns:prefix="namespace URI"`. Here's an example in an XML document:

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com">
    <foo:test />
</foo:root>
```

We've now bound namespace `http://www.foo.com` to the prefix `foo`. Wherever this prefix is put in front of an element or attribute's name, we're stating that they're part of that namespace.

What's very important to note here is that the actual prefix means absolutely nothing. The following XML document is semantically the exact same:

```
<bar:root xmlns:bar="http://www.foo.com">
    <bar:test />
</bar:root>
```

The prefix is merely a convenient way of representing the namespace. It saves us from having to use the URI entirely every time.

Next up is the default namespace. A default namespace can be declared with `xmlns="namespace URI"`. You could abstractly think of this as binding a namespace to the empty prefix. Once again the same XML document, but this time without prefixes:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.foo.com">
    <test />
</root>
```

This is a bit more convenient to work with. So why have prefixes at all? They start playing a role when we're mixing content from different namespaces:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.foo.com">
    <so:test xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com" />
</root>
```

This time it's a different XML document. Our `root` element lies in the `http://www.foo.com` namespace, but the `test` element lies in `http://stackoverflow.com` because we've bound to `so` prefix to that and used it on `test`.

You also notice here that namespaces can be declared on any element in the XML document. The **scope** of that declaration (and binding to prefix if applicable) then becomes that element and its content.

This can sometimes become confusing, even more so since declarations may override each other. Check this document:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.foo.com">
    <test />
    <so:test xmlns:so="http://www.stackoverflow.com" xmlns="http://www.bar.com">
        <test />
    </so:test>
</root>
```

Take a moment and figure out what namespace each element is in... It's a good excercise.

`root` is in namespace `http://www.foo.com`. The first `test` element is also in that namespace, since we haven't used a prefix but we're in the scope of that default namespace. The second `test` element with prefix `so` lies in namespace `http://www.stackoverflow.com` because that's what we bound the prefix to.

So then there's the third, innermost `test` element. What namespace is it in? It doesn't have a prefix, so it must be in the default namespace. BUT, we've changed our default namespace in the second test element! So now that innermost element belongs to the `http://www.bar.com` namespace, not `http://www.foo.com`.

Confused yet? Just remember the following:

- A namespace is just a string. URIs are used as a convenient way to have unique identifiers.
- A prefix is used to represent a namespace, but its name holds no meaning whatsoever. Just think of it as a placeholder.
- You can set a default namespace. All elements within its scope that don't have a prefix then become part of it.

---

Phew. Now, onto W3C XML Schema. How does all of this relate to it?

Well, for starters XML Schema itself is a markup language defined in XML. So it stands to reason that it gets its own namespace. And that namespace is officially `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. If you write that `S` as lower case, it's wrong. Starting to see why some people really hate namespaces?

The following three documents are exactly the same:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xsd:schema>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xs:schema>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</schema>
```

All that matters is that we're using stuff from the XML Schema namespace. As a convention, however, people tend to use prefix `xs` or `xsd` in XML Schemas.

When we have an XML document, we may wish to specify where the schema(s) for it are located. More than one schema can be relevant for an XML document, because as we've stated languages can be mixed in XML. In order to say that an XML document is an instance of a schema, once again there's a special namespace available: `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. By convention, we tend to bind this namespace to prefix `xsi`. But again, this isn't mandatory.

There's a couple of attributes defined in that schema instance namespace. Among them are `schemaLocation` and `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`. Take a look at this document:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.foo.com/schema">
</root>
```

What happend there? First we stated that we're binding prefix `xsi` to the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. Then we're used an attribute within that namespace: `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`. That attribute tells us where the schema is located to validate those parts of the document that aren't in any particular namespace. The following XML document is exactly the same, semantically:

```
<root xmlns:huh="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" huh:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.test.com/schema">
</root>
```

Remember, prefix names have no meaning. They're placeholders. So, what's with that `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute? Basically, it tells us where we can locate a schema. Now contrary to a namespace URI, this is most definitely something that can be used to fetch stuff from a network or local storage. An XML processor that validates against a schema declared in a document might try to obtain it.

Then there's the fact that it's called `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`. A schema defines a "target namespace". What this does is state what namespace the elements and attributes it defines are part of. But the target namespace may be omitted. In that case, we've got a schema for XML documents without namespace. Such a schema can be referred to with `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

In many cases, a schema will actually define a namespace. In order to say which schema belongs with which namespace, we can use another attribute from the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace: `schemaLocation`. That attribute can contain pairs (separated by spaces) of namespace URIs and schema URIs. Suppose we have schema for namespace `http://www.foo.com` located at `http://www.myschemas.com/foo-schema`. Then we can state that as follows:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.com http://www.myschemas.com/foo-schema">
</root>
```

Here's an example with multiple namespace-location pairs:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.com http://www.myschemas.com/foo-schema http://www.bar.com http://www.randomschemas.com/bar-schema">
</root>
```

What you need to remember here is that `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` stuff is for use in XML documents that are instances of schemas. The namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` is the one used for defining schemas themselves.

---

So by now we're up to our neck in URIs and weird-looking attributes with special meanings. That's the thing with namespaces: they look very complex until you figure out how simple they are. Just keep a close eye on what prefix is bound to what namespace URI, and know what that URI defines.

There's two more things about schemas I need to address for your question: `xs:import` and `xs:include`. Notice how I've used the `xs` prefix convention here, since we're talking about W3C XML Schema.

The include element can be used to combine schemas **with the same target namespace**. Basically it allows us to modularize schemas into smaller parts and put them together.

The import element does sort of the same, but for schemas **with different target namespaces**. This allows us to combine schemas for different markup languages.

---

So to recap:

- `xmlns`: used to specify a default namespace.
- `xmlns:prefix`: used to bind a namespace to `prefix`.
- `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`: the namespace for XML Schema. By convention often bound to prefix `xs`, but this is not mandatory nor is it done automatically.
- `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`: the namespace that defines a bunch of things useful for declaring the details of how an XML document is an instance of a schema. By convention often bound to prefix `xsi`, but this is not mandatory nor is it done automatically.
- `targetNamespace`: an attribute that can be used in XML Schema (on the root element) to specify for which namespace this is a schema definition.
- `schemaLocation`: one of the attributes defined by namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, used to indicate where one or more schemas can be found for one or more namespaces.

My final advice: find some convenient way to validate documents against schemas and play around a bit. Experiment with namespaces, includes and imports. Make documents using multiple namespaces and try out the scoping.

After that, check the specifications of XML itself, XML namespaces and XML Schema. It's hardcore reading, but if you make your way through it you'll gain an understanding that many people still seem to miss after years of using XML. Eventually it'll all make sense.

Good luck!

Comment: This is epic - should be the definitive answer to this type of question, if stack overflow supported this feature. Thanks for posting this I learned a lot and can see why my answer was indeed limited.

Comment: @hugh It's not even complete... For attributes, prefixes have somewhat deviating rules. They're not qualified by default. But I'm not entirely certain whether that places them into the element's namespace or not, so I'm careful to make statements about it. And there's more stuff I could've mentioned, but the truth is that only the specs can provide definitive answers.

Comment: G_H it is extremely rare that someone takes the time to answer a question as throughly as this. Thank you!

Comment: @G_H, attributes will always end up in the empty namespace by default, even when attached to elements in a namespace. To put an attribute into a namespace, a prefix must always be used. I think that, most of the time, it only makes sense for attributes to be put in their own namespace when they would be annotating an element from an unrelated namespace. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46865/429091) explains why this makes sense, be sure to read *beyond* its blockquote!.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your queries:

1. **`xmlns`** - a unique value used in instance documents to indicate which schema the XML is an instance of (or what schema it will validate against). Even though the namespace does not identify the actual schema file, there should be one schema which defines this namespace.
2. **`xmlns:xs`** - called *namespace prefixes* and by convention used in instance documents to indicate where the types used in the XML are coming from. You can think of this like `using` in C# or `imports` in VB. For example, `xmlns:xs="http://mySharedTypes"` says that in this XML some of my types come from the namespace "http://mySharedTypes", and these types will be prefixed with "xs".
3. **`xmlns:xsi`** - as above. Infact the xs and xsi prefixes are by convention used when referencing the W3C schema namespaces http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema and http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance. However these namespace prefixes are just convention and can actually be anything.
4. **`targetNamespace`** - a unique value you put in your schema definition which gives the types you define in the schema their namespace. So if someone wants to use the types in your schema then they must include an `xmlns` attribute with the same values as your targetNamespace.
5. **`xs:import schemaLocation`** - This is conventionally a relative path to another schema, although not all xml processors recognise it. So you can optionally link to another schema in your `xs:import` as a kind of shortcut to the schema file itself. The other attribute in the import is the schema targetNamespace, which is mandatory.
6. **`xsi:schemaLocation`** - Although this shares the same name as the import attribute it is not the same definition. By convention, the xsi namespace prefix refers to types from the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance namespace, which are used inside instance documents, rather than schema documents.

Sorry if the above is not clear, it's a little bit of an open-ended question and there is a ton of material you could write for any one of these points. If you need clarity on any of the points please ask - I will be happy to provide, or alternatively create a new question with narrower scope.

Comment: This information is not entirely accurate. `xmlns` indicates a default namespace, it has nothing to do whatsoever with indicating a schema. There's some other mistakes. They might be minor, but when it comes to namespaces and XML Schema the smallest thing can quickly become confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much hugh; this is the best, most thorough, and easy to understand explanation of this stuff I have comes across. One last thought: what if you are constructing schema-compliant XML on the fly (in memory, as, say, a string): do you always need to put this xmlns, xs, xsi, etc. stuff in the "instance string" in order to validate it, or is it possible to just tell a parser what schema to validate XML against; then to include all those defs in the schema?

Comment: @G_H Thanks for your comment. Please feel free to edit my answer or please indicate other inaccuracies and I will incorporate into my answer.

Comment: @zharvey I think you need to include it all for validation purposes. Otherwise the validator will not know which namespaces the types you are usinig come from.

Comment: @zharvey Some parsers may use schema locations defined in an XML document for validation. Some may not. Often it can be configured. However, it is usually better to validate against a schema you appoint yourself, rather than relying on some location given in an XML document. If you do that, you don't actually need any schema location info in the XML document itself.

Comment: Very, very sorry hugh - I gave you the answer yesterday as it was truly a great answer. But I think we can all agree that G_H went above and beyond with his latest answer. Hate to give you the green and then take it away, but I did upvote your answer and I do thank you profusely for taking the time to help me understand this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

- `xmlns="uri1"` and `xmlns:whatever="uri2"` are namespace node and not attributes. Their role is to say that when you see element in your XML document named `whatever:myElement`, then the element belongs to the "whatever" namespace. This "whatever namespace" is identified by the uri declared in the namespace node.
- `targetNamespace` is an attribute. It contains an URI that identify the elements, types and group you define in your schema.
- xsi:schemaLocation is quite different. It's an attribute that allow XML parsers to find the schema attached to an XML instance. You don't need it in schema.
- With `xs:import` you can import schemas from different namespace to use their elements and types in your own schema. When using `xs:import`, the imported schema and the importing schema must have different namespace. Use `xs:include` if it's the same namespace.