# Does the namespace of an XML element extend to its attributes?

Tags: xml, namespaces

[Duplicate question:  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865/989516) for answer ("No, don't qualify the attributes")]

This is my first time working with XML namespaces, and I want to make sure I'm doing this right.  Strangely, for such a simple thing, I can't find anything on SO that addresses the question:

I've got a namespace-qualified XML element with some attributes.  Do the attributes need to be qualified too, or does the scope extend to them?

```
<foo:tag value="bar" />
```

or

```
<foo:tag foo:value="bar" />
```

Comment: Attributes do need to be qualified (unless belonging to the default namespace).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/46865/989516

Comment: @KevinCollins Sure enough, already been asked.  Thanks!