# What is the behavior of getAttributeNS?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom

I'm writing a little program in JavaScript in which I want to parse the following little XML snippet:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" other="attributes">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item subscription="both" jid="romeo@example.com"></item>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Because I don't know, if the elements and attributes have namespace prefixes, I'm using the namespace-aware functions (`getElementsByTagNameNS`, `getAttributeNS`).

```
var queryElement = iq.getElementsByTagNameNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'query')[0];
if (queryElement) {
  var itemElements = queryElement.getElementsByTagNameNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'item');
  for (var i = itemElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var itemElement = itemElements[i];

    var jid = itemElement.getAttributeNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'jid');
  };
};
```

With this code I don't get the value of the attribute `jid` (I get an empty string), but when I use `itemElement.getAttribute('jid')` instead of `itemElement.getAttributeNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'jid')` I'm getting the expected result.

How can I write the code in a namespace-aware manner? In my understanding of XML, the namespace of the attribute `jid` has the namespace `jabber:iq:roster` and therefore the function `getAttributeNS` should return the value `romeo@example.com`.

[UPDATE] The problem was (or is) my understanding of the use of namespaces together with XML attributes and is not related to the DOM API. Therefor I created an other question: [XML Namespaces and Unprefixed Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672635/xml-namespaces-and-unprefixed-attributes). Also because [XML namespaces and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561/xml-namespaces-and-attributes) unfortunately doesn't give me an answer.

[UPDATE] What I did now, is to first check if there is the attribute without a namespace and then if it is there with a namespace:

```
var queryElement = iq.getElementsByTagNameNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'query')[0];
if (queryElement) {
  var itemElements = queryElement.getElementsByTagNameNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'item');
  for (var i = itemElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var itemElement = itemElements[i];

    var jid = itemElement.getAttribute('jid') || itemElement.getAttributeNS('jabber:iq:roster', 'jid');

  };
};
```

Comment: I have no experience with XML namespaces, but from what I'm seeing from demos online, the first argument (which represents the XML namespace) is an URI.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas The namespace 'jabber:iq:roster' is a correct URI defined in the specs of [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#roster-syntax-actions-get).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing is that [**attributes don't get the namespace until you explicitly prefix them with it**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting):

`A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names`

This is unlike elements that do inherit the default namespace from the parent unless have their own defined. With that said, your attributes are not namespaced and that's why `getAttribute()` works and `getAttributeNS()` with a namespace value doesn't.

Your source XML would need to look something like this to "namespace" the attribute:

```
<a:query xmlns:a="jabber:iq:roster">
    <a:item a:subscription="both" a:jid="romeo@example.com"></a:item>
</a:query>
```

Here's some more on the subject: [XML namespaces and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561/xml-namespaces-and-attributes).

If you want to only use the namespace-aware methods then it should (not sure though, might be implementation specific) work for you with `null` namespace. Try `getAttributeNS(null, "jid")`. If it doesn't, you can always work around it with the `hasAttributeNS()` and only then a fallback to `getAttributeNS()` or `getAttribute()`.

Comment: First thanks for pointing me to the spec for **Namespaces in XML**. I guess my understanding of namespaces within XML attributes was wrong (at least I'm confused now). ;-) But what does the phrase _the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear._ mean?

Comment: I guess it means that the attributes belong to an element rather than a namespace. There are exceptions, of course, like `xml:lang` for example, but the majority of attributes only make sense in context of a particular element.