# PHP Parse XML with colon in tag name using children

Tags: php, xml

I have the following php code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://openclipart.org/api/search/?query=dog&page=1");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $clipinfo):
  $title=$clipinfo->title;
  $full=$clipinfo->enclosure['url'];
  $thumb=$clipartinfo->children('media', true)->thumbnail['url'];

  echo "<div style=\"width:160px;height:120px;float:left;margin:5px;margin-top:10px;\">    
  <a href=\"{$full}\" target='_blank' class=\"thumbnail\">
  <img alt=\"{$title}\" style=\"width: 160px; height: 120px;\" src=\"{$thumb}\">
  </a>
  </div>";
endforeach;
```

This is being fed by the following XML file:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title>OpenClipart.org</title>
    <atom:link rel="self" href="http://openclipart.org/api/search/?query=dog&amp;page=1" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <link>http://openclipart.org</link>
    <description>Download, Sample, Cut-up, Share.</description>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <image>
    <url>http://openclipart.org/assets/images/images/logo-no-text.jpg</url>
    <link>http://openclipart.org</link>
    <title>OpenClipart.org</title>
    <height>93</height>
    <width>114</width>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>walking dog</title>
      <link>http://openclipart.org/detail/720/walking-dog-by-johnny_automatic</link>
      <pubDate>Tue, 17 Oct 2006 21:23:37 -0400</pubDate>
      <dc:creator>johnny_automatic</dc:creator>
      <description>cartoon of a girl walking a dog from  http://www.usda.gov/cnpp/KidsPyra/National Agricultural Library, Agricultural Research Service, U. S. Department of Agriculture</description>
      <enclosure url="http://openclipart.org/people/johnny_automatic/johnny_automatic_walking_dog.svg" type="image/svg+xml" length="99841"/>
      <guid>http://openclipart.org/detail/720/walking-dog-by-johnny_automatic</guid>
      <cc:license>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain</cc:license>
      <media:thumbnail url="http://openclipart.org/image/90px/svg_to_png/720/johnny_automatic_walking_dog.png"/>
    </item>
```

Why can't I get the `<media:thumbnail>` url attribute with my foreach statement? (I have already read [PHP library for parsing XML with a colons in tag names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names)) This is a different issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you're using an undefined variable in your `foreach` loop. You've defined `$clipinfo` but you're trying to use `$clipartinfo` in your code.

Second, you're accessing the attributes incorrectly:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://openclipart.org/image/foo.png"/>
```

You're trying to access the URL attribute. This needs to be done with [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method.

Change:

```
$thumb=$clipartinfo->children('media', true)->thumbnail['url'];
```

to:

```
$thumb = $clipinfo->children('media', true)->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That fixed the problem where the entire foreach statement wasn't working. However, the variable $thumb still returns null.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! You were the first and only person to not rudely send me to that other answer!

Comment: To be clear, in general, `['url']` would be the *right* way to access an attribute; the problem comes when namespaces are involved. (The other answer pointed to was explaining that "colon in tag name" is actually an "XML namespace"; once you are using the right terms, help will be easier to find.)

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are not automatically in the same namespace as the element they appear on. If the XML contained `<media:thumbnail media:url="...." />`, then the attribute would be in the namespace currently assigned the prefix `media`, the same namespace as the `thumbnail` element, and your code would work fine.

However, a quirk of the XML namespace specification is that "The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value." - that is, an attribute without a namespace prefix is explicitly not in any namespace, regardless of what else is defined in the document. (See also [XML Namespaces and Unprefixed Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10672635/157957))

In SimpleXML, this means if you've switched to a specific namespace with `->children`, you have to explicitly switch back to the "null" namespace to access the attribute, using [the `->attributes()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes). This should work:

```
 $thumb = $clipinfo->children('media', true)->thumbnail->attributes(null)->url;
```