# How to easily parse XML documents with namespaces in PHP using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse YouTube's top 15 videos feed. An excerpt of the feed I am trying to parse looks like the following:

```
<entry>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <link href="http://example.com" />
    <media:thumbnail url="http://example.com/image.png" />
    <media:description>The Description</media:description>
    <media:statistics views="123456" />
    <pubDate>29/01/2017</pubDate>
</entry>
```

I am unable to capture any of the values that use the tags beginning with `<media:`. I am using the following code to parse the data; commented lines are those that don't work.

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $val) {
    echo "<item>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<title>".$val->title."</title>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<link>".$val->link["href"]."</link>".PHP_EOL;
    //echo "<image>".$val->media:thumbnail["url"]."</image>".PHP_EOL;
    //echo "<description>".$val->media:description."</description>".PHP_EOL;
    //echo "<views>".$val->media:statistics["views"]."</views>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<pubDate>".$val->published."</pubDate>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "</item>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

How can I get the values of these tags without setting up namespaces. doing a `var_dump` on `$xml->entry` doesn't even show the namespaced elements. Is there a better, built in function for converting XML into arrays?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed (i.e., invalid). According to the [W3C Namespaces in XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-using): *the namespace prefix, unless it is xml or xmlns, MUST have been declared in a namespace declaration attribute*. So `media` prefix should be declared.

Comment: A lot more difficult then with DOM+Xpath. Register own prefixes on the DOMXpath instance and use DOMXpath::evaluate() to fetch node lists and values.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but the method you're looking for is [`->children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php). In your case `$val->children('media', true)->description` would work, although I'd recommend hard-coding the actual namespace URI (from the `xmlns:media` attribute) rather than the prefix, in case the source document is regenerated with different prefixes.

Comment: @ThW XPath doesn't seem like a good fit for this use case to me, and learning to use it and the DOM feels more complex than a few calls to `->children()` and `->attributes()`.

Comment: @Parfait It's an excerpt, not a full document; hence it's also missing the `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` declaration. The `xmlns:media` attribute will be at the unshown root of the document. That said, it would be great if it could be converted to a [mcve] with those parts added back in.

Comment: @IMSoP It is really simple: https://eval.in/726878

Comment: @ThW Sure, easy enough if you already know XPath. For comparison, here's how I'd write it in SimpleXML: https://eval.in/726881 Personally, I find SimpleXML more readable in general, although there's not much in it in this case; but it's certainly not "a lot more difficult". The only fiddly bit is the `->attributes(null)`, because [unprefixed attributes are a bit of an anomaly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10673325/157957).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer from the [code provided by IMSoP](https://eval.in/726881). The PHP snippet I ended up using was adapted from aforementioned link, using XML similar to that of the OP:

```
foreach ($xml->children(NS_ATOM)->entry as $entry) {
    echo "<item>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<title>".$entry->title."</title>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<link>".$entry->link->attributes(null)->href."</link>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<image>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->group->children(NS_MEDIA)->thumbnail->attributes(null)->url."</image>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<description>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->group->children(NS_MEDIA)->description."</description>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<guid>".$entry->children(NS_YT)->videoId."</guid>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<views>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->group->children(NS_MEDIA)->community->children(NS_MEDIA)->statistics->attributes(null)->views."</views>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<pubDate>".$entry->published."</pubDate>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "</item>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Hope this can help somebody in the future. It was the easiest example of XML namespace parsing I've come across so far.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the sibling to XPath, as you are essentially transforming original XML, not really parsing select values. With XSLT, you would need no `foreach` loop and can adequately handle namespaces.

In fact as shown below XSLT is the fastest of aforementioned methods ( `SimpleXML` querying and `XPath` evaluating) using posted XML wrapped in a `<feed ...>` root:

**Simple XML** *(from @IMSoP)*

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$xml = file_get_contents('YoutubeFeed.xml');
$document = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
define('NS_ATOM', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
define('NS_MEDIA', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

foreach ($document->children(NS_ATOM)->entry as $entry) {
    echo "<item>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<title>".$entry->title."</title>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<link>".$entry->link->attributes(null)->href."</link>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<image>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->thumbnail->attributes()->url."</image>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<description>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->description."</description>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<guid>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->guid."</guid>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<views>".$entry->children(NS_MEDIA)->statistics->attributes()->views."</views>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<pubDate>".$entry->published."</pubDate>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "</item>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Timing

```
echo "SimpleXML: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start) ."\n";
# SimpleXML: 0.0014688968658447
```

**XPATH** *(from @ThW)*

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$xml = file_get_contents('YoutubeFeed.xml');
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xpath->registerNamespace('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//atom:entry') as $entry) {
   echo "<item>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<title>". $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:title)', $entry)."</title>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<link>". $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link/@href)', $entry)."</link>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<image>". $xpath->evaluate('string(media:thumbnail/@url)', $entry)."</image>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<description>". $xpath->evaluate('string(media:description)', $entry)."</description>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<guid>". $xpath->evaluate('string(media:guid)', $entry)."</description>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<views>".$xpath->evaluate('string(media:statistics/@views)', $entry)."</guid>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "<pubDate>". $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:pubdate)', $entry)."</views>".PHP_EOL;
   echo "</item>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Timing

```
echo "XPATH: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start) ."\n";
# XPATH: 0.0012829303741455
```

**XSLT**

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$xml = file_get_contents('YoutubeFeed.xml');
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);

$xslstr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="atom media">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="feed">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
      <item>
         <title><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></title>
         <link><xsl:value-of select="atom:link/@href"/></link>
         <image><xsl:value-of select="atom:thumbnail/@url"/></image>
         <description><xsl:value-of select="media:description"/></description>
         <guid><xsl:value-of select="media:guid"/></guid>
         <views><xsl:value-of select="media:statistics/@views"/></views>
         <pubDate><xsl:value-of select="atom:pubdate"/></pubDate>
      </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>';

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($document);

// Echo string output
echo $newXML;
```

Timing

```
echo "XSLT: " . (microtime(true) - $time_start) ."\n";
# XSLT: 0.00098896026611328
```

---

Even with more `<entry>` nodes, copying tag and children to 500 lines, XSLT scales much better. Below units are in seconds:

```
# SimpleXML: 0.62154388427734

# XPATH: 0.68382000923157

# XSLT: 0.011976957321167
```