# PHP - Namespace Shift in Child Node in SimpleXML Troubleshooting

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm working with SimpleXML and XPath in trying to get the value of a child node's ('IndexEntry) attribute ('indexKey').  The node's namespace, I've tested successfully on another node ('Record').
For some reason, this node's attribute ('indexKey') is not returning.  I've tried accessing the node, while specifying its namespace, by using the children method.

PHP Code

```
<?php
$url = "test_bb.xml";


$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('dmd','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata');

$xml_report_abbrev_bb = $xml->xpath('//a:Record[@username="john-smith"]');

if($xml_report_abbrev_bb){
    echo '<br>CONTYPE is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->INTELLCONT->CONTYPE;
    echo '<br>termId is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]['termId'].'<br>';
    echo '<br>surveyId is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->attributes('dmd',true)['surveyId'].'<br>';

//below - I've tried different methods of accessing the IndexEntry node...
    $dmd_fields = $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->children('dmd',true);
    echo '<br>dmd:IndexEntry is...'.$dmd_fields->IndexEntry['indexKey'].'<br>';

    echo '<br>dmd:IndexEntry is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->children('dmd',true)->IndexEntry['indexKey'].'<br>';

    //echo '<br>dmd:IndexEntry is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->IndexEntry('dmd',true)['indexKey'].'<br>';

    //echo '<br>dmd:IndexEntry is...'.$xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->xpath('/dmd:indexEntry[@indexKey]')[0].'<br>';


} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed b';  
}

?>
```

XML ('test_bb.xml')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2012-01-03">
    <Record userId="148" username="john-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="12">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
            </INTELLCONT>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
$dmd_fields = $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->children('dmd', true);
```

This will mean that `$dmd_fields` will be a list of nodes, even though there is only one node in the list - so use `$dmd_fields[0]` to reference the `<dmd:IndexEntry>` element.  As this is the `IndexEntry` element, just using this and the list off attributes for that element you can do...

```
echo '<br>dmd:IndexEntry is...'.$dmd_fields[0]->attributes()['indexKey'].'<br>';
```

Comment: Referencing an item from a list of nodes by name should work just fine; SimpleXML is designed to be very forgiving about that.

Comment: Thanks - I just tend to not like relying on when things 'should' happen.  One of my biggest problems with PHP and some frameworks is that a lot of things tend to happen by 'magic'.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `IndexEntry` element is in the `http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata` namespace, as denoted by the local prefix `dmd:`, its attributes *have no prefix*:

```
<dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
```

Unprefixed *elements* in this document are in the `http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data` namespace, as specified in the `xmlns=` attribute on the root node.

But as [discussed on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672635/xml-namespaces-and-unprefixed-attributes), the XML namespace spec says that attributes are never in the default namespace. This puts them, peculiarly, in *no namespace at all*, so to access them with SimpleXML, you have to select the namespace whose URI is the empty string:

```
$dmd_fields->IndexEntry->attributes('')->indexKey;
```