# Getting media url attribute from SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, rss, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I want to get 'url' attribute from 'media:content' tag of a RSS using simplexml.
I searched the net for hours but cannot get it to work.
This is the code:

```
<?php
$rss ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <media:content url="http://blog.com/image1.jpg" width="661" height="310"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);
$url = $xml->children('media', true)->content;

var_dump($xml);
var_dump($url); // <- This is object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
var_dump($url['url']); // <- This is NULL
```

The $url is NULL. ->content returns a SimpleXMLElement but it hasn't any url attribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) with for example this expression to get the media:content element:

`/rss/channel/item/media:content`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);
$urls = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item/media:content');

// Get url from the first match
echo $urls[0]->attributes()->url;

// Loop all the matches
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url->attributes()->url;
}
```

[Php demo output](https://3v4l.org/Rj4uq)

Or you can loop though the children for this item:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item->children("media", true) as $child) {
    echo $child->attributes()->url;
}
```

[Php demo output](https://3v4l.org/o3Phg)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have to make sure that your fetching the right `content` element, so make sure that you fetch the full path of the content node (note the extra path in setting up the `$url` variable).  Then there are some oddities of fetching the attributes of a namespaced element (I believe they do not have a namespace themselves), to access them you have to use the `attributes()` method and then fetch the element using `['url']`.  You can try the added options...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);
$url = $xml->channel->item->children('media', true)->content;

var_dump($xml);
var_dump($url); // <- This is object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
var_dump($url['url']); // <- This is NULL
var_dump($url->attributes()['url']);
echo "url-".(string)$url->attributes()['url'].PHP_EOL;
```

The last two lines give you...

```
class SimpleXMLElement#6 (1) {
  public ${0} =>
  string(26) "http://blog.com/image1.jpg"
}
url-http://blog.com/image1.jpg
```

(echo will cast the value to a string anyway, but I put this in just in case you try assigning the value and wanted the value rather than the SimpleXMLElement object)

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution too.

Comment: Yes, [unprefixed attributes are always in no namespace at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672635/xml-namespaces-and-unprefixed-attributes). As a matter of style, you can also write `$url->attributes()->url`, and you can use `->attributes(null)` if you want to be explicit about "I'm selecting the null-namespace here".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are ignoring the *media* namespace.

In [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/) you can find more about how to address tags with a namespace specified.

In the example the namespace is passed to the `children` member function to scope the `media:content` tag.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);
$url = $xml->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->content;

var_dump($xml);
var_dump($url); // <- This is object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
var_dump($url['url']); // <- This is NULL
```

Comment: children('media', TRUE) is identical to what you wrote. See this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_children.asp