# SimpleXml with namespace issues

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have tried almost everything but i cannot seem to read the namespaced "m:inline" element and the "feed" and "title" children from the following SimpleXMLElement dump:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#235
+"@attributes": array:4 [
    "rel" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/test"
    "type" => "application/atom+xml;type=feed"
    "title" => "some title"
    "href" => "JobRequisition(23453453L)/Test"
]
+"m:inline": SimpleXMLElement {#152
  +"feed": SimpleXMLElement {#123
    +"title": "jobReqLocale"

...some more data ahead skipped here
```

The raw xml start:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/jobReqLocale" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="some title" href="JobRequisition(23453453L)/Test">
        <m:inline>
            <feed>
                <title type="text">jobReqLocale</title>

...
```

I have tried:

```
$simpleXmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOERROR, false);

dd($simpleXmlElement->children('m', true)->feed);
```

The result is always an empty SimpleXmlElement

with all kinds of variations including xpath. Am i doing something wrong? Is SimpleXML not supporting these kinds of structures?

Comment: Please can you [edit] to include a sample of XML you're trying to parse, rather than whatever debug output that is? SimpleXML tends to display badly in most generic debug, because it doesn't have "real" properties.

Comment: I have added the  start of the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Your document contains (at least) two namespaces: one with the local prefix `m`, and one with no prefix (the "default namespace"). It may actually contain other namespaces you haven't shown, or re-assign both the `m:` prefix and the default namespace at different points in the document, but *within the fragment you've shown*:

- The `inline` element is in the namespace with local prefix `m`
- The `link`, `feed`, and `title` elements are in the default namespace
- The various attributes [are in no namespace at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672635/xml-namespaces-and-unprefixed-attributes); peculiarly, this isn't the same as them being in the default namespace.

As discussed on "[Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)" the `->children()` method *switches namespaces*, so:

- To select the `inline` element, you would use `->children('m', true)->inline`
- To select the `feed` element inside it, you need to switch *back* to the default namespace, with `->children(null, true)->feed`
- To access the `title` element inside that, you will already be in the default namespace, so can just use `->title`
- In this particular case, it doesn't matter if you are in the default namespace or "no namespace", so the `type` attribute can be accessed directly with `['type']`
- Remember to cast any attribute or element to string to get its string content

To summarise:

```
$type = (string)$simpleXmlElement
    ->children('m', true)
            ->inline
    ->children(null, true)
            ->feed
            ->title
            ['type'];
```

Note that ideally you'd hard-code the namespace URIs, which are not subject to change, rather than the prefixes. You could also avoid assuming which is the default namespace and explicitly select the null namespace when selecting attributes. That would give you something more like this:

```
$type = (string)$simpleXmlElement
    ->children(XMLNS_SOMETHING)
            ->inline
    ->children(XMLNS_OTHER_THING)
            ->feed
            ->title
    ->attributes(null)
            ->type;
```