# Why SVG use element created with JavaScript is not shown?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG in my document and I add a symbol to it with JavaScript like this:

```
var myScene =document.getElementById('myScene');
var useSVG = document.createElement('use');
useSVG.setAttribute('xlink:href','spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol');
useSVG.setAttribute('x','10');
useSVG.setAttribute('y','30');
useSVG.setAttribute('width','10');
useSVG.setAttribute('height','10');
myScene.appendChild(useSVG);
```

The symbol does not show up whereas the resulting code is exactly the same as another node written in HTML which is displayed correctly.

Code shown in debugger:

```
<svg id="myScene" width="200px" height="200px">
    <use xlink:href="spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol" x="5" y="50" width="10" height="10"></use>
    <!-- this one was in html, it is visible -->
    <use xlink:href="spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol" x="10" y="30" width="10" height="10"></use>
    <!-- this one is added with javascript. it is not displayed -->
</svg>
```

Comment: the answer below is not enough but points to the right direction. Here you also have to use `document.createElementNS` instead of `document.createElement` to create the `use` element. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488884/add-svg-element-to-existing-svg-using-dom) solved the similar problem.

Comment: I've tried everything, I can't make it work. Can't find a working example neither. My solution is to give an ID to the hard coded USE tag and duplicate it with node.cloneNode(). Still looking for a working example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `createElementNS()` to create SVG elements.  The basic `createElement()` creates elements in the HTML namespace.  So you basically have been creating `<html:use>` elements instead of `<svg:use>` ones.

```
var myScene =document.getElementById('myScene');
var useSVG = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
useSVG.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol');
useSVG.setAttribute('x','10');
useSVG.setAttribute('y','30');
useSVG.setAttribute('width','10');
useSVG.setAttribute('height','10');
myScene.appendChild(useSVG);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5kth2af/)

**Update**

I have just realised there is a second problem with your code.  You are using an external reference in your `href` (it's referenceing a symbol in another file).  It seems IE doesn't support external references.

I found more info, and a possible workaround, here: http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

Comment: Thank you... but it works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 10. Do you have an Idea why ?

Comment: You might need to do `useSVG.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xlink:href','spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol');` on IE. Try that. If it still doesn't work, please post a jsfiddle so we can see your code.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe it's because I use a SVG symbol, I,ll try later with groups

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure to 100% but I think you need to set the `xlink:href` Attribute using `setAttributeNS()` like this:

```
useSVG.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol');
```

Also make sure that the namespace is declared within your document.

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<!-- or if standalone svg -->

<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

However, this way I solved the same issue within an xhtml document, probably that will work for html5 or standalone SVG, too.

[xlink specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/)

good luck!

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't work ;( Thank you anyway.
It does write href attribute without the 'xlink' of xlink:href.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to create SVG elements you must use createElementNS(), not createElement().  But even then, createElementNS() won't properly create an SVG "use" element.  It appears to work, but the resulting "use" won't be displayed.

Workaround 1: clone an existing "use" element, then modify it via setAttributeNS().  (In my experience, setAttribute() also works on SVG elements.)

```
var useSVG = another_useSVG.cloneNode(true);
myScene.appendChild(useSVG);
useSVG.setAttribute('xlink:href','spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol');
```

Workaround 2: create a group element, then assign it's innerHTML to get the desired "use" element.

```
var myScene = document.getElementById('myScene');
var group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
group.innerHTML = "<use xlink:href='spriteSheet.svg#mySymbol' x='10' y='30' width='10' height='10'/>";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I just figured it out! When creating the svg element with `document.createElement("svg")`, you just have to use the correct namespace.
And it works even with other elements like path, line, rect etc

So this

```js
document.createElement("svg");
```

Becomes that

```js
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
```

And this

```js
document.createElement("use");
```

Becomes that

```js
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","use");
```

In case you wondering, you **don't** have to use `element.setAttributeNS`, `element.setAttribute` will work