# JS successfully appends a tag, web page fails to display though

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The function below is meant to insert a `<polygon></polygon>` into an `<svg id = "svg-overlays"></svg>`.

I can see that the element gets successfully inserted when the function is called. However, the polygon is still not visible. If I do the insertion manually within the html document I get the desired polygon.

Unable to determine what the issue is here.

```
 function changeFloorImage(floor) {

        var overlays = document.getElementById("svg-overlays");
        var polygon = document.createElement("polygon");

        polygon.className = "apartment-overlay";
        polygon.setAttribute("points", "740,88 972,88 972,353 740,353");

        overlays.appendChild(polygon);
    };
```

Comment: Tags are markup, the DOM has elements  (hence *createElement*). ;-)

Comment: you need to create svg element like this: `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
```

You need to specify SVG name space. There are several examples in stackoverflow.

[Creating SVG elements dynamically with javascript inside HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539196/creating-svg-elements-dynamically-with-javascript-inside-html)

[Add SVG element to existing SVG using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488884/add-svg-element-to-existing-svg-using-dom)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the references. Problem solved now.