# How to add svg using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using this code to insert svg into a div tag.

```
var container = document.getElementById("div_id");
var svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("width",container.clientWidth);
svg.setAttribute("height",container.clientHeight);    
container.appendChild(svg);
```

On checking using the developer tools in the browser, svg is present inside the div. But when I hover over the svg in the developer tools, it is showing "svg 0*0" i.e eventhough the width and height attributes are set as 500 and 400 I cannot view it in the page. I tried to insert a line into the svg, which again can be seen inside svg, but not visible in the browser. Need help.

Comment: [Your code appears to work just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/uf822snd/) (Using Firefox.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
```

to create your SVG. Use it for elements as well.

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'circle');
```

The work just like regular elements.

Comment: The link you provided don't cover the issue specifically (it's hidden in there) and it's not obvious how to search or ask for this info. Hardly worth a down vote when I'm sure my 30 seconds taught him something.

Comment: @Wainage Do I have to use 'createElementNS' for every element that needs to be created, or should I use it only for the '<svg></svg>' and 'createElement' for the elements inside it.

Comment: @KarthikManivasgam All your SVG elements (path, circle, rect ...) need createElementsNS

Comment: I will make your reply as the answer. And friends if you have alternate solutions, you are always welcome