# Remove namespace and prefix from xml in python using lxml

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I have an xml file I need to open and make some changes to, one of those changes is to remove the namespace and prefix and then save to another file.
Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer">
  <provider>some data</provider>
  <language>en-GB</language>
</package>
```

I can make the other changes I need, but can't find out how to remove the namespace and prefix. This is the reusklt xml I need:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<package>
  <provider>some data</provider>
  <language>en-GB</language>
</package>
```

And here is my script which will open and parse the xml and save it:

```
metadata = '/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/metadata.xml'
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
open(metadata)
tree = etree.parse(metadata, parser)
root = tree.getroot()
tree.write('/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/done.xml', pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

So how would I add code in my script which will remove the namespace and prefix?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Replace tag as Uku Loskit suggests. In addition to that, use [lxml.objectify.deannotate](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#xml-schema-datatype-annotation).

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

metadata = '/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/metadata.xml'
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(metadata, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

####    
for elem in root.getiterator():
    if not hasattr(elem.tag, 'find'): continue  # guard for Comment tags
    i = elem.tag.find('}')
    if i >= 0:
        elem.tag = elem.tag[i+1:]
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)
####

tree.write('/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/done.xml',
           pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Note: Some tags like `Comment` return a function when accessing `tag` attribute. added a guard for that.

Comment: The find() on elem.tag will fail if it is the built-in function Comment. You'll want to check for a string with something like the following: if isinstance(elem.tag, basestring): do_something(). This is for 2.x. Use isinstance(elem.tag, str) in 3.x.

Comment: @JeffLoughridge, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: if you can condense code by `rpartition`. for elem in root.getiterator():    _, _, el.tag = el.tag.rpartition('}')

Answer (score 101):

We can get the desired output document in two steps:

1. Remove namespace URIs from element names
2. Remove unused namespace declarations from the XML tree

**Example code**

```py
from lxml import etree

input_xml = """
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer">
  <provider>some data</provider>
  <language>en-GB</language>
  <!-- some comment -->
  <?xml-some-processing-instruction ?>
</package>
"""
root = etree.fromstring(input_xml)

# Iterate through all XML elements
for elem in root.getiterator():
    # Skip comments and processing instructions,
    # because they do not have names
    if not (
        isinstance(elem, etree._Comment)
        or isinstance(elem, etree._ProcessingInstruction)
    ):
        # Remove a namespace URI in the element's name
        elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname

# Remove unused namespace declarations
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)

print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

**Output XML**

```
<package>
  <provider>some data</provider>
  <language>en-GB</language>
  <!-- some comment -->
  <?xml-some-processing-instruction ?>
</package>
```

**Details explaining the code**

As described in the [documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces), we use [`lxml.etree.QName.localname`](https://lxml.de/4.1/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html#section-Properties) to get local names of elements, that is names without namespace URIs. Then we replace the fully qualified names of the elements by their local names.

Some XML elements, such as comments and processing instructions do not have names. So, we have to skip these elements while replacing element names, otherwise a `ValueError` will be raised.

Finally, we use [`lxml.etree.cleanup_namespaces()`](https://lxml.de/4.1/api/lxml.etree-module.html#cleanup_namespaces) to remove unused namespace declarations from the XML tree.

**Note on namespaced XML attributes**

If the XML input contains attributes with explicitly specified namespace prefixes, the example code will not remove those prefixes.  To accomplish the deletion of namespace prefixes in attributes, add the following for-loop after the line `elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886208/6942134)

```py
        for attr_name in elem.attrib:
            local_attr_name = etree.QName(attr_name).localname
            if attr_name != local_attr_name:
                attr_value = elem.attrib[attr_name]
                del elem.attrib[attr_name]
                elem.attrib[local_attr_name] = attr_value
```

To learn more about namespaced XML attributes see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865/6942134)

Comment: Cool: The only clean solution of all answers.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. Seriously, regexes to remove curly braces from tag names? +1

Comment: It's a clean solution, but for 1.2M items, it becomes slower:
`x = etree.QName(item).localname: 8.87s` / `x = item.tag: 5.43s`

Answer (score 8):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def remove_namespace(doc, namespace):
    """Remove namespace in the passed document in place."""
    ns = u'{%s}' % namespace
    nsl = len(ns)
    for elem in doc.getiterator():
        if elem.tag.startswith(ns):
            elem.tag = elem.tag[nsl:]

metadata = '/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/metadata.xml'
tree = ET.parse(metadata)
root = tree.getroot()

remove_namespace(root, u'http://apple.com/itunes/importer')
tree.write('/Users/user1/Desktop/Python/done.xml',
       pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Used a snippet of code from [here](http://homework.nwsnet.de/releases/45be/)
This method could be easily extended to delete any namespace attributes by searching for tags that begin with "xmlns"

Comment: this is nice.  For those trying to implement in recent versions of Python 3 (I'm running 3.9), the line 'for elem in doc.getiterator():' needs to be 'for elem in doc.iter():'

Comment: and the pretty_print kwarg seems to have been deprecated.  see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

Answer (score 6):

You could also use XSLT to strip the namespaces...

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("metadata.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")

new_tree = tree.xslt(xslt)

print(etree.tostring(new_tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, 
                     encoding="UTF-8").decode("UTF-8"))
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<package>
  <provider>some data</provider>
  <language>en-GB</language>
</package>
```

Answer (score 4):

Define and call the following function, right after you parse the XML string:

```py
from lxml import etree

def clean_xml_namespaces(root):
    for element in root.getiterator():
        if isinstance(element, etree._Comment):
            continue
        element.tag = etree.QName(element).localname
    etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
```

> Note - comment elements in the XML are ignored, as they should be

Usage:

```py
xml_content = b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this dependency is critical -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
clean_xml_namespaces(root) 
elements = root.findall(".//dependency")
print(len(elements)) 
# outputs "2", as expected
```

Answer (score 4):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972010/191246) removes namespaces in node *names* **but not** in *attributes*, i.e. `<b:spam c:name="cheese"/>` will be transformed to `<spam c:name="cheese"/>`.

An updated version which will give you `<spam name="cheese"/>`

```py
def remove_namespaces(root):
    for elem in root.getiterator():

        if not (
                isinstance(elem, etree._Comment)
                or isinstance(elem, etree._ProcessingInstruction)
        ):

            localname = etree.QName(elem).localname
            if elem.tag != localname:
                elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname

            for attr_name in elem.attrib:
                local_attr_name = etree.QName(attr_name).localname
                if attr_name != local_attr_name:
                    attr_value = elem.attrib[attr_name]
                    del elem.attrib[attr_name]
                    elem.attrib[local_attr_name] = attr_value

    deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try with lxml:

```
# Remove namespace prefixes
for elem in root.getiterator():
    namespace_removed = elem.xpath('local-name()')
```

Comment: probalby a typo? should be `elem.tag = elem.xpath('local-name()') ` ?

Comment: @Max Yes, it is a typo. Fixed it. Thak you.

Comment: @lechat Please explain how this works. Doesn't work for me, I don't get any children from this.

Answer (score 2):

So I realize this is an older answer with a highly up-voted and accepted answer, but if you are reading **LARGE-FILES** and find yourself in the same predicament I did; I hope this helps you out.

The issue with this approach is, in fact, the iteration. Regardless of how fast the parser is, doing anything say... a few 100k times is gonna eat your execution time. With that said, it came down to really thinking about the problem for me and understanding how namespaces work (or are "intended to work", because they are honestly not needed). Now if your xml *truly* uses namespaces, meaning you see tags that look like this: `<xs:table>`, then you'll need to tweak the approach here for your use-case. I'll include the full way of handling, as well.

#### DISCLAIMER : I cannot, with a good conscience, tell you to use regular expressions when parsing html/xml, go look at SergiyKolesnikov's answer as it WORKS, but I had an edge case so with that said... let's dive into some regex!

Problem: namespace stripping takes forever... and most of the time the namespaces only live inside of the very opening tag, or our "**root**". So in thinking about how python reads information in, and where our only problem-child is that root node, why not use that to our advantage.

Please NOTE: the file i'm using as my example comes as a raw, horrid, remarkably senseless structure of lulz with the promise of data in there somewhere.

`my_file` is the path to the file im using for our example, I cannot share it with you for professional reasons; and it has been cut down way in size just to get through this answer.

```py
import os, sys, subprocess, re, io, json
from lxml import etree

# Your file would be '_biggest_file' if playing along at home
my_file = _biggest_file
meta_stuff = dict(
    exists = os.path.exists(_biggest_file), 
    sizeof = os.path.getsize(_biggest_file),
    extension_is_a_real_thing = any(re.findall("\.(html|xml)$", my_file, re.I)),
    system_thinks_its_a = subprocess.check_output(
        ["file", "-i", _biggest_file]
    ).decode().split(":")[-1:][0].strip()
)


print(json.dumps(meta_stuff, indent = 2))
```

So for starters, decently sized, and system thinks at best it's html; the file extension is neither xml or html either...

```json
{
  "exists": true,
  "sizeof": 24442371,
  "extension_is_a_real_thing": false,
  "system_thinks_its_a": "text/html; charset=us-ascii"
}
```

Approach:

1. In order to parse an xml file... it should at the very least be xml, so we'll need to check and add a declarations tag if one doesn't exist
2. If I have namespaces.. thats bad because I can't use xpaths, which is what I want to do
3. If my file is huge, I should only operate on the smallest imaginable parts that I need to clean before I'm ready to parse it.

#### Function

```py
def speed_read(file_path):

    # We're gonna be low-brow and add our own using this string. It's fine
    _xml_dec = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    # Even worse.. rgx for xml here we go
    # 
    # We'll need to extract the very first node that we find in our document, 
    # because for our purposes thats the one we know has the namespace uri's 
    # ie: "attributes"
    #    FiRsT node : <actual_name xmlns:xsi="idontactuallydoanything.com">
    # We're going to pluck out that first node, get the tags actual name
    # which means from:
    #    <actual_name xmlns:xsi="idontactuallydoanything.com">...</actual_name>
    # We pluck:
    #    actual_name
    # Then we're gonna replace the entire tag with one we make from that name
    # by simple string substitution
    # 
    # -> 'starting from the beginning, capture everything between the < and the >'
    _first_node = re.compile('^(\<.*?\>)', re.I|re.M|re.U)
    # -> 'Starting from the beginning, but dont you get me the <, find anything that happens
    #     before the first white-space, which i don't want either man'
    _first_tagname = re.compile('(?<=^\<)(.*?)\S+',re.I|re.M|re.U)
    # open the file context
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        # go ahead and strip leading and trailing, cause why not... plus adds 
        # safety for our regex's
        _raw = f.read().strip()
        # Now, if the file somehow happens to magically have the xml declaration, we
        # wanna go ahead and remove it as we plan to add our own. But for efficiency, 
        # only check the first couple of characters
        if _raw.startswith('<?xml', 0, 5):
            #_raw = re.sub(_xml_dec, '', _raw).strip()
            _raw = re.sub('\<\?xml.*?\?>\n?', '', _raw).strip()
        # Here we grab that first node that has those meaningless namespaces
        root_element = _first_node.search(_raw).group()
        # here we get its name
        first_tag = _first_tagname.search(root_element).group()
        # Here, we rubstitute the entire element, with a new one
        # that only contains the elements name
        _raw = re.sub(root_element, '<{}>'.format(first_tag), _raw)
        # Now we add our declaration tag in the worst way you have ever
        # seen, but I miss sprintf, so this is how i'm rolling. Python is terrible btw
        _raw = "{}{}".format(_xml_dec, _raw)
        # The bytes part here might end up being overkill.. but this has worked 
        # for me consistently so it stays. 
        return etree.parse(io.BytesIO(bytes(bytearray(_raw, encoding = "utf-8"))))



# a good answer from above:

def safe_read(file_path):
    root = etree.parse(file_path)
    for elem in root.getiterator():
        elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname
    # Remove unused namespace declarations
    etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
    return root
```

#### Benchmarking - Yes I know there's better ways to do this.

```py
import pandas as pd

safe_times = []
for i in range(0,5):
    s = time.time()
    safe_read(_biggest_file)
    safe_times.append(time.time() - s)


fast_times = []
for i in range(0,5):
    s = time.time()
    speed_read(_biggest_file)
    fast_times.append(time.time() - s)


pd.DataFrame({"safe":safe_times, "fast":fast_times})
```

## Results

---

| safe | fast |
| --- | --- |
| 2.36 | 0.61 |
| 2.15 | 0.58 |
| 2.47 | 0.49 |
| 2.94 | 0.60 |
| 2.83 | 0.53 |

Comment: Thanks for documenting this - i was thinking about this approach with the exact same use case, though I do need the other attribute tags in the root node (which from test your method removes?) Is there were an easy way to modify the regex to remove only the xmlns="..." tag?

Comment: @Spcoggthesecond so it sounds like you do actually need the namespace tags?

Comment: no i don't want the ns tag, but there are other tags in the first node i need. It's just annoying because the data source has only a single ns declared and doesn't use it anywhere in the xml tree itself.

Comment: @Spcoggthesecond lol I'm starting to wonder if we have a mutual third party. If you can paste the node in question in here I'll be able to answer the regex question for sure

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other ways of removing namespaces. The first uses the lxml.etree.QName helper while the second uses regexes. Both functions allow an optional list of namespaces to match against. If no namespace list is supplied then all namespaces are removed. Attribute keys are also cleaned.

```
from lxml import etree
import re

def remove_namespaces_qname(doc, namespaces=None):

    for el in doc.getiterator():

        # clean tag
        q = etree.QName(el.tag)
        if q is not None:
            if namespaces is not None:
                if q.namespace in namespaces:
                    el.tag = q.localname
            else:
                el.tag = q.localname

            # clean attributes
            for a, v in el.items():
                q = etree.QName(a)
                if q is not None:
                    if namespaces is not None:
                        if q.namespace in namespaces:
                            del el.attrib[a]
                            el.attrib[q.localname] = v
                    else:
                        del el.attrib[a]
                        el.attrib[q.localname] = v
    return doc


def remove_namespace_re(doc, namespaces=None):

    if namespaces is not None:
        ns = list(map(lambda n: u'{%s}' % n, namespaces))

    for el in doc.getiterator():

        # clean tag
        m = re.match(r'({.+})(.+)', el.tag)
        if m is not None:
            if namespaces is not None:
                if m.group(1) in ns:
                    el.tag = m.group(2)
            else:
                el.tag = m.group(2)

            # clean attributes
            for a, v in el.items():
                m = re.match(r'({.+})(.+)', a)
                if m is not None:
                    if namespaces is not None:
                        if m.group(1) in ns:
                            del el.attrib[a]
                            el.attrib[m.group(2)] = v
                    else:
                        del el.attrib[a]
                        el.attrib[m.group(2)] = v
    return doc
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is:

```
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)
```

after you have get the root, by using `root = tree.getroot()`

Comment: This will not remove namespace declarations from the tree's root node.