# How to keep xml namespace without prefix, while generating XML using lxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to create simple SVG (XML) file as follows:

```
root = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg')
root.append(element) # element is a <path> element extracted from another SVG file
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

But this gives the output as follows:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><ns0:path ...></ns0:path></ns0:svg>
```

This output is almost correct, but how do I get rid of the `ns0:` namespace it seems to have added randomly? The expected output is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path ...></path></svg>
```

I've tried using `nsmap` as follows, but this raises `ValueError: Invalid namespace prefix ''`:

```
root = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg', nsmap={'': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'})
# ...
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972010/2741678) comes close, but it removes the namespace prefix **and** the namespace, which I don't really want – I want to remove the namespace *prefix*, but preserve the namespace (as it wouldn't be a valid SVG without the namespace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. In `nsmap=`, instead of `''`, use `None`:

```
root = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}svg', nsmap={None: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'})
root.append(element) # element is a <path> element extracted from another SVG file
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

This will preserve the namespace, but not add any namespace prefix (i.e. `ns0`).