# Python xml parser with namespaces

Tags: python, xml, namespaces

Dears,
I have an xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http:/xxxx//bb/v1 /xyz/it/Data/v1/Data-1_2.xsd" version="1.2" xmlns="http://xx/it//Data/v1">
  <Header>
    <Location>abc</Location>
    <Date start="date-time"/>
```

I am trying to parser different tags and attributes. however, xmln seems to mess up the parsing.
I am using code like

```
tree = ET.parse(input_filename)
root = tree.getroot()
location = tree.find("./Header/Location").text
time = tree.find("./Header/Date").attrib['start']
```

This works perfectly when I manually remove all xmln attributes in the <Data tag from the input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data >
  <Header>
    <Location>abc</Location>
    <Date start="date-time"/>
```

but keeping it give an error

```
location = tree.find("./Header/Location").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I tried almost 90% of pervious suggestions still no good results.
Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Python version support wildcards for namespaces. Consider this:-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http:/xxxx//bb/v1 /xyz/it/Data/v1/Data-1_2.xsd" version="1.2" xmlns="http://xx/it//Data/v1">
  <Header>
    <Location>abc</Location>
    <Date start="date-time"/>
  </Header>
</Data>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

location = tree.find('.//{*}Header/{*}Location').text
_time = tree.find('.//{*}Header/{*}Date').attrib['start']

print(f'Location={location}, time={_time}')
```

Comment: thanks, this should do for the code, but gave me issues in other parts where I used root.iter
This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160164/16726552  worked very well without having to change anything in code for with and without xmlns.