# Java DOM default namespace

Tags: java, dom, namespaces, default

I want to create an XML with a default namespace using DOM:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<test xmlns="example:ns:uri" attr1="XXX" attr2="YYY">
  <el>bla bla</el>
</test>
```

I have the following

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
resultingDOMDocument = db.newDocument();
Element rootElement =
   resultingDOMDocument.createElementNS("example:ns:uri", "test-results-upload");
rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns", "example:ns:uri");
rootElement.setAttributeNS("example:ns:uri", "attr1", "XXX");
rootElement.setAttributeNS("example:ns:uri", "attr2", "YYY");
```

And I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<test xmlns="example:ns:uri" ns0:attr1="XXX" xmlns:ns0="example:ns:uri" ns1:attr2="YYY" xmlns:ns1="example:ns:uri">
  <el>bla bla</el>
</test>
```

I am using standard DOM API in the JDK v6. What am I doing wrong ?
I want to underline - I want to use the default namespace and I DON'T want to use namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to use the default namespace and I DON'T want to use namespace prefixes

The default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`) only applies to elements, not to attributes.  Therefore if you create an attribute in a namespace then the serializer *must* bind that namespace URI to a prefix and use that prefix for the attribute in order to serialize the DOM tree accurately, even if the same URI is also bound to the default `xmlns`.  Unprefixed attribute names always mean *no* namespace, so in order to generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<test xmlns="example:ns:uri" attr1="XXX" attr2="YYY">
  <el>bla bla</el>
</test>
```

you need to put the elements in the namespace

```
Element rootElement =
   resultingDOMDocument.createElementNS("example:ns:uri", "test-results-upload");
```

but the attributes not:

```
rootElement.setAttributeNS(null, "attr1", "XXX");
rootElement.setAttributeNS(null, "attr2", "YYY");
```

Comment: Thank You IAN - your answer is very useful - I must admit that I wasn't aware of that important fact. Here is the link [http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting] to XML spec and another answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561/xml-namespaces-and-attributes]