# C# XML deserialization - missing value - Why?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, openoffice-impress

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0" xmlns:anim="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:animation:1.0" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" office:version="1.2" grddl:transformation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/1.2/xslt/odf2rdf.xsl">
    <office:meta>
        <meta:creation-date>2014-09-16T11:15:44.96</meta:creation-date>
        <meta:editing-duration>PT00H01M36S</meta:editing-duration>
        <meta:editing-cycles>2</meta:editing-cycles>
        <dc:date>2014-09-16T11:17:09.59</dc:date>
        <meta:document-statistic meta:object-count="24" />
        <meta:generator>OpenOffice.org/3.2$Win32 OpenOffice.org_project/320m12$Build-9483</meta:generator>
    </office:meta>
</office:document-meta>
```

Now I want to deserialize the XML.

I get the meta information like creation-date, date, and generator, but object-count is NULL instead of 24, and doc.version is also NULL, while it should be 1.2. 
What am I doing wrong ?

```
OpenOffice.ODP.Meta.DocumentMeta mydoc = Tools.XML.Serialization.DeserializeXmlFromFile<OpenOffice.ODP.Meta.DocumentMeta>(@"D:\UserName\Tests\Presentation_1.odp\meta.xml");

string ver = mydoc.Version;    
Console.WriteLine(mydoc);
Console.WriteLine(ver);
```

Serialization class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace Tools.XML
{


    // http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization
    // http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xml_serializationasp.aspx
    public class Serialization
    {


        public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T ThisTypeInstance, string strFileNameAndPath)
        {
            SerializeToXml<T>(ThisTypeInstance, new System.IO.StreamWriter(strFileNameAndPath));
        } // End Sub SerializeToXml


        public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T ThisTypeInstance)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            string strReturnValue = null;

            SerializeToXml<T>(ThisTypeInstance, new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));

            strReturnValue = sb.ToString();
            sb = null;

            return strReturnValue;
        } // End Function SerializeToXml


        public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T ThisTypeInstance, System.IO.TextWriter tw)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (System.IO.TextWriter twTextWriter = tw) 
            {
                serializer.Serialize(twTextWriter, ThisTypeInstance);
                twTextWriter.Close();
            } // End Using twTextWriter

            serializer = null;
        } // End Sub SerializeToXml


        public static T DeserializeXmlFromFile<T>(string strFileNameAndPath)
        {
            T tReturnValue = default(T);

            using (System.IO.FileStream fstrm = new System.IO.FileStream(strFileNameAndPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)) 
            {
                tReturnValue = DeserializeXmlFromStream<T>(fstrm);
                fstrm.Close();
            } // End Using fstrm

            return tReturnValue;
        } // End Function DeserializeXmlFromFile


        public static T DeserializeXmlFromEmbeddedRessource<T>(string strRessourceName)
        {
            T tReturnValue = default(T);

            System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();


            using (System.IO.Stream fstrm = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(strRessourceName)) 
            {
                tReturnValue = DeserializeXmlFromStream<T>(fstrm);
                fstrm.Close();
            } // End Using fstrm

            return tReturnValue;
        } // End Function DeserializeXmlFromEmbeddedRessource


        public static T DeserializeXmlFromStream<T>(System.IO.Stream strm)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T ThisType = default(T);

            using (System.IO.StreamReader srEncodingReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strm, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) 
            {
                ThisType = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(srEncodingReader);
                srEncodingReader.Close();
            } // End Using srEncodingReader

            deserializer = null;

            return ThisType;
        } // End Function DeserializeXmlFromStream


        #if notneeded

        public static void SerializeToXML<T>(System.Collections.Generic.List<T> ThisTypeInstance, string strConfigFileNameAndPath)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<T>));

            using (System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strConfigFileNameAndPath)) {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, ThisTypeInstance);
                textWriter.Close();
            }

            serializer = null;
        }
        // SerializeToXML


        public static System.Collections.Generic.List<T> DeserializeXmlFromFileAsList<T>(string strFileNameAndPath)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<T>));
            System.Collections.Generic.List<T> ThisTypeList = null;

            using (System.IO.StreamReader srEncodingReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strFileNameAndPath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
                ThisTypeList = (System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)deserializer.Deserialize(srEncodingReader);
                srEncodingReader.Close();
            }

            deserializer = null;

            return ThisTypeList;
        }
        // DeserializeXmlFromFileAsList

        #endif

    } // End Class Serialization


} // End Namespace COR.Tools.XML
```

XML holder:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace OpenOffice.ODP.Meta
{


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "document-statistic", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
    public class cDocumentStatistic
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "object-count", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public string ObjectCount { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "meta", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0")]
    public class Meta
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "creation-date", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public string CreationDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "editing-duration", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public string EditingDuration { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "editing-cycles", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public string EditingCycles { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date", Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "document-statistic", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public cDocumentStatistic DocumentStatistic { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "generator", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0")]
        public string Generator { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "document-meta", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0")]
    public class DocumentMeta
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "meta", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0")]
        public Meta Meta { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "meta", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string _Meta { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "office", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Office { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xlink", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xlink { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "dc", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Dc { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "presentation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Presentation { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ooo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Ooo { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "smil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Smil { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "anim", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Anim { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "grddl", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Grddl { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "officeooo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Officeooo { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "transformation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#")]
        public string Transformation { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Additional question:
Does anybody know what the duration format is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the deserializer is buggy. 
Because the standard says you **can omit** the attribute namespace if the element namespace is the same. On the other hand, that obviously doesn't mean you **absolutely have to omit** the attribute namespace just because the element namespace is the same.

See [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561/xml-namespaces-and-attributes).

The solution is to somehow set a root-namespace that is not the same as the containing namespace, but leave the actual root-namespace unaffected...

If one has a XmlElement, that's possible because you can set XmlRoot there if you have it in a separate class, and set another namespace in the class where it is actually referenced.

In code,  that's simply:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "document-statistic", Namespace = "")]
public class cDocumentStatistic
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "object-count", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" )]
    public string ObjectCount { get; set; }
}
```

The solution for version is a bit more complex: since it's an attribute, you cannot set xmlroot in the serializer (whyever that is as it is, that is the actual bug)...

So you have to hack together a XmlTextReader that ignores the namespaces on version, but doesn't ignore them on the rest... That goes like this

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization
    // helper class to ignore namespaces when de-serializing
    public class NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader : System.Xml.XmlTextReader
    {
        public NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(System.IO.TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

        public override string NamespaceURI
        {

            get
            { //return ""
                // string nam = base.Name;
                // Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
                // Console.WriteLine(this.LocalName);

                if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(this.Name, "office:version"))
                {
                    return "";
                }



                // Console.WriteLine(nam);
                return base.NamespaceURI;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you still have to tell the serializer to actually use this abdomination

```
public static T DeserializeXmlFromStream<T>(System.IO.Stream strm)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T ThisType = default(T);



    using (System.IO.StreamReader srEncodingReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strm, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) 
    {
        // ThisType = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(srEncodingReader);

        using (NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader SpecialNamespaceReaderBecauseMicrosoftSucks = new NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(srEncodingReader))
        {
            ThisType = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(SpecialNamespaceReaderBecauseMicrosoftSucks);
            SpecialNamespaceReaderBecauseMicrosoftSucks.Close();
        } // End Using SpecialNamespaceReaderBecauseMicrosoftSucks

        srEncodingReader.Close();
    } // End Using srEncodingReader

    deserializer = null;

    return ThisType;
} // End Function DeserializeXmlFromStream
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and found that you need to make few changes to your file.

Please note that you need not specify the namespace for object_count and version as both their tags have their namespace specified in the start
for *version* office is specified in the tag itself **office:document-meta**

same for *object_count* namespace meta is specified in the tag **meta:document-statistic**

Here is the updated one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<office:document-meta 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" 
xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0" 
xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" 
xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0" 
xmlns:anim="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:animation:1.0" 
xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" 
xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" 
version="1.2" 
grddl:transformation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/1.2/xslt/odf2rdf.xsl">
    <office:meta>
        <meta:creation-date>2014-09-16T11:15:44.96</meta:creation-date>
        <meta:editing-duration>PT00H01M36S</meta:editing-duration>
        <meta:editing-cycles>2</meta:editing-cycles>
        <dc:date>2014-09-16T11:17:09.59</dc:date>
        <meta:document-statistic object-count="24" />
        <meta:generator>OpenOffice.org/3.2$Win32 OpenOffice.org_project/320m12$Build-9483</meta:generator>
    </office:meta>
</office:document-meta>
```

Hope this helps
:)

Comment: That works, but that's not good, I can't modify OpenOffice, which is where the XML comes from and goes to... The problem must be somehow solved by modifying the class, not the XML file. And I certainly don't want to start poking around with Replace in an XML document.