# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize XmlAnyAttribute?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class, that has an object:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34283")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class Scores : baseModel
{
   private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;
   /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
   public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr
  {
      get
      {
         return this.anyAttrField;
      }
      set
      {
         this.anyAttrField = value;
      }
   }
}
```

From the parent class (snippet of it):

```
public parial class LandingPage : baseModel
{
    private string projectNameField;
    private Scores scoresField;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string projectName
    {
        get { return this.projectNameField; }
        set { this.projectNameField = value; }
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Scores scores
    {
        get { return this.scoresField; }
        set { this.scoresField = value }
    }
}
```

The JSON string I'm trying to work with:

```
{
    "projectName":"PROJECTTEST",
    "scores":{
        "browLocker":100,
        "heavyAd":0,
        "walletRedirection":0
    }
}
```

NewtonSoft.JsonConvert ignores the scores child fields...

How can I easily convert this to work?

Comment: Why would Json.NET care about an XML attribute? Why don't you create a pair of classes that actually matches the JSON document?

Comment: Why are you making your life harder by trying to convert JSON to XML when you can just work with the JSON you have?

Comment: Change your `Scores` class to `class Scores{public int BrowLocker {get;set;} public int HeavyAd {get;set;} public int WalletRedirection{get;set;}}`. You don't need anything else to deserialize this string

Comment: Thanks...  the problem is the results may include additional elements..  so how do I handle something that can have 1 of the elements, or 5...

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me.  It looks like you are trying to deserialize some JSON into some classes that were generated for working with XML.  Is it a requirement that you use these specific classes, or are you free to use other classes if it makes things easier to deserialize?  Also, when you say "something can have 1 of the elements or 5", what are you referring to?

Comment: Does `Scores` have any properties besides the `AnyAttr` member that need to be serialized from and to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `Scores` type has no properties of its own to serialize, you can create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for it that converts the `XmlAttribute []` array to a `Dictionary<string, string>` then serializes that dictionary in place of the `Scores` object:

```
public class XmlAttributeArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(XmlAttribute[]);
    } 

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader);
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        return dict.Select(p => { var a = doc.CreateAttribute(p.Key); a.Value = p.Value; return a; }).ToArray();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // TODO: determine how to represent XmlAttribute values with non-empty NamespaceURI - or throw an exception.
        var attributes = (IEnumerable<XmlAttribute>)value;
        var dict = attributes.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dict);
    }
}

class ScoresConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Scores);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var attributes = (XmlAttribute[])new XmlAttributeArrayConverter().ReadJson(reader, typeof(XmlAttribute[]), null, serializer);
        return new Scores { AnyAttr = attributes };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var scores = (Scores)value;
        if (scores.AnyAttr == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else
        {
            new XmlAttributeArrayConverter().WriteJson(writer, scores.AnyAttr, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note I extracted some of the logic into a separate `XmlAttributeArrayConverter` in case it might be of use elsewhere.)

Then apply it to `Scores` as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ScoresConverter))]
public partial class Scores
{
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIFQXu).

Note if one of the XML attributes happens to be in a namespace (most of the time [none will be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561/xml-namespaces-and-attributes)) then the namespace is not serialized.  If your attributes might have namespaces you will need to decide how to convert the attribute's full name to a JSON property name.  `{namespace}localname` would be one possibility, that is what is used by [`XName.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).