# Missing attribute namespace when using default namespace with lxml

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I am using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) v4.4.1

When I parse a MathML document which use a namespace prefix (for instance `xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"`), element and attribute names are prefixed by "{http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML}", which it normal.

example 1:

```py
from lxml import etree

XML1 = """<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mml:display="block"/>"""
math = etree.XML(XML1)
print(math.tag)
print(math.attrib)
# {http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML}math
# {'{http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML}display': 'block'}
```

But, when I use the default namespace (eg.: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"`), attributes are not prefixed by the MathML namespace.

example 2:

```py
XML2 = """<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"/>"""
math = etree.XML(XML2)
print(math.tag)
print(math.attrib)
# {http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML}math
# {'display': 'block'}  # <-- WRONG
```

Is it a bug? How to work around that?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. Default namespace declarations (no prefix) do not apply to attribute names. This means that attributes without a prefix are not in a namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41561/407651, http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/NamespaceMyths.htm#myth4.

Comment: You are right! I have found the reference here : https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting. It is really surprising. It says: **The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value.**.